# How to fix animation insert rows table view iOS 15*

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

When iOS 15, i don`t disable animation insert rows from table view

[image]

And videos:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6-NcwiVynFW42IqWnv-YtaWuI9GWLi7/view?usp=sharing

Code:

```
       self.messageViewModel.loadMoreMessages { messages, hasNextPage in
            guard !messages.isEmpty else { return }
            var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
            for (index, message) in messages.enumerated() {
                self.messages.insert(message, at: index)
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
            }
            MAIN_QUEUE.async {
                if self.listMessage.contentOffset.y > 0 {
//                    TODO: BUG iOS 15
                    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                        self.listMessage.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
                    } else {
                        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
                        self.listMessage.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
                        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
                    }
                    self.hasNextPage = hasNextPage
                    return
                } else {
                    self.indexPathsLoadMore = indexPaths
                    self.hasNextPageLoadMore = hasNextPage
                    return
                }
            }
        }
```

I would disable animation when insert rows from table view.

#ios #mobile #swift

Please help me. Thanks you!

Comment: Have you tried:
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.listMessage.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
}